# How do I access the Principal in a Message Driven Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jaas, message-driven-bean

In the onMessage method of a MDB, how can I retrieve the name of the JAAS User Principal that initiated the request?  My application is using Servlet login and a jdbcRealm.

I have considered adding this as a Message Property, but I would rather ensure that this is handled by JAAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is handled inherently, all that you have to do is to inject and use `MessageDrivenContext`:

```
..
@Resource
private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    Principal principal = mdc.getCallerPrincipal();
    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    //ALTERNATIVELY, YOU CAN USE A METHOD mdc.isCallerInRole("<role name>");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding documentation, you can find introduction about MDBs and example in the official Oracle documentation, but I agree, it can be more detailed definitely.